# Magento: customize special price observer fails in cart

Tags: magento, observer-pattern, cart

i've built a special price observer similar to the example explained in the [magento wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method)
but now i'm facing the problem, that the "new" price is only shown within the catalog, but not within the shopping cart or totals..

I've also tried to apply it using

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product_get_final_price',array('product'=>product));
```

within the _getProduct() in the Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart class

Do i have to rewrite my observer for sales_order_place_after or something like this?

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Use the "`sales_quote_collect_totals_before`" / "`sales_quote_collect_totals_after`" event, which fires every time when totals changes.

It is called withing the "`collectTotals()`" method in `Quote.php`, every time the cart gets updated, and at other events

Comment: thanks.. hm, this solves the total problem, but the display of the product prices within the cart won't be affected... and i'll have to duplicate my code on 3 different places.

Comment: you will have to extend the blocks in a few different areas to change the renders.